# How do I get this piece of code run faster?

Tags: performance-tuning

Here is a piece of my code, in which I have a function that includes sums over the multiplication of `ThreeJSymbols`. I am using this function in a multiple loops to calculate potentials. Does anybody know of ways to make it way faster?

```
 ℓ0 = 4;
 γ = 
  Join[Table[{m, 1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}], 
  Table[{m, -1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}]]
  nstates = 2*(2 ℓ0 + 1);
  ne = 2 ℓ0 + 2;

  avec = Table[0, {ie, 1, ne}, {i, 1, nstates}];
  Do[avec[[1, i]] = 1;
  avec[[j, nstates - (i - 1)]] = 1, {i, 1, nstates/2}, {j, 2, ne}]

ParallelEvaluate[Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
ClearAll[dfxn]; 
dfxn[ℓ_, m1_, m2_, p1_, p2_] := 
N@If[m1 + p1 == m2 + p2, 
 Sum[(2 ℓ + 1)^2 (2 ℓtemp + 1)/(4 π )
    Sum[If[m1 + p1 == mval && m2 + p2 == mval, 
     ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ, m1}, {ℓ, 
        p1}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ, 
        m2}, {ℓ, 
        p2}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ, 
        0}, {ℓ, 0}, {ℓtemp, 0}]^2, 
     0], {mval, -ℓtemp, ℓtemp}], \
     {ℓtemp, 0, 2 ℓ}], 0];];

    vdir =(*(2 ℓ0 +1)^2*) Chop[ParallelTable[

    mpf = γ[[f, 1]];
    mk = γ[[k, 1]];
    μpf = γ[[f, 2]];
    μk = γ[[k, 2]];
    Total[   
    Table[
    Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
    μpi = γ[[i, 2]];
    μpj = γ[[j, 2]];
    pi = γ[[i, 1]]; 
    pj = γ[[j, 1]];
    If[μpi == μpj && μpf == μk, 
    N[Conjugate[avec[[ie, i]]] *avec[[ie, j]]* 
     dfxn[ ℓ0, pi, mk, mpf, pj]], 0]
   , {ie, 1, ne}, {i, 1, nstates}, {j, 1, nstates} ]
   , Infinity ] 
   , {f, 1, nstates}, {k, 1, nstates}]];
```

Comment: Your code throws errors because `avec` is unknown.

Comment: I added avec. Thank you

Comment: A simple change gets this done in ~5 seconds on my laptop. Is that quick enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll go ahead and post this quick speed improvement pending your reply to my question.

Replace references to `ThreeJSymbol` in your code with `j3s`, and add

```
ClearAll[j3s];
j3s[a_, b_, c_] := j3s[a, b, c] = ThreeJSymbol[a, b, c];
```

to the top of your code.

This will redefine `j3s` for known values as they are computed (a kind of memoization), and results in a better than order of magnitude speed increase for execution.

Comment: Thank you Ciao, This helps but since I am looking for large ne and it's a part of a larger loop, it still take a long time and I am wondering if It can still get improved. (sorry I was in the class, couldn't reply quickly)

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi - how large?

Comment: I have two potential functions calling the dfxn in each iteration, and I need to run it for ne>=16 in a two outer loops ( 20 iteration for the larger loop and each loop 5 inner iteration means total 100 iteration at least )